# How to achieve always compareTo method should be consistent with the equals method in TreeMap or TreeSet?

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

**How to achieve always?**

The `compareTo` method or `compare` method should be consistent with the `equals` method of the object being stored in `TreeMap` or `TreeSet`?

Comment: This is spelled out in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Maybe you can explain how you are having trouble with this.

Comment: While starting

    `int compareTo(T other) {
        if (equals(other))
            return 0;
        if (null == other) ...`
ensures `equals(other)` implies `0 == compareTo(other)`, there still might be cases where `0 == compareTo(other) = 0` but `!equals(other)`, necessitating `natural ordering inconsistent with equals` not only in the doc comment of `compareTo`, but of the class, also. Anyway, `equals(other)` implying `0 == compareTo(other)` might be irreconcilable with what you are trying to achieve in the first place.